# I am getting an error 'left parenthesis missing'

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table emp1 with emp_no as primary key and dept_id as foreign key of another table dept. While I am creating, it is throwing an error saying that "left parenthesis missing".

Could anyone of you help me to solve the below query?

```
create table emp1
(
    emp_no int primary key,
    emp_name char(20),
    hire_date date,
    salary int,
    emp_manager_id varchar(20),
    constraint fk_emp_manager_id foreign key references dept(dept_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it that way. Several objections:

- always name constraints; if you don't, Oracle will create default name which doesn't tell you *anything* and you'll have problems identifying it
- don't use `CHAR` if you don't have a good reason. Storing names into `CHAR` datatype column is wrong; it'll be right-padded to column's full length with spaces, and you'll have to `TRIM` it every time you want to do *something* with it
- don't use `VARCHAR` datatype - use `VARCHAR2`
- why is `EMP_MANAGER_ID` column's datatype `VARCHAR`? I presume it should be `INT`, just like `EMP_NO`. Don't they serve the same purpose?
- foreign key constraint you tried to create is completely misleading. Its name is `FK_EMP_MANAGER_ID`, suggesting that you're referencing employee (i.e. `EMP_NO` in the same `EMP1` table). However, `references` clause references another table, so ... what are you *really* trying to do? I presume latter (regarding problems you have; it is a simpler case than the former).

So:

```
SQL> create table emp1
  2  (
  3      emp_no         int constraint pk_emp primary key,
  4      emp_name       varchar2(20),
  5      dept_id        int,
  6      hire_date      date,
  7      salary         int,
  8      emp_manager_id int,
  9      --
 10      constraint fk_emp_dept foreign key (dept_id) references dept(dept_id)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for foreign key is wrong, you did not specify which column(s) are the foreign key. And coincidentally those columns would be put in parenthesis, so you are missing one.

In the future do look up some examples and try to format your code, spotting mistakes is much easier on properly formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is an error in your foreign key, (dept_id) is missing.
2. You have no column dept_id in your create table statement.

The correct statement is:

```
create table emp1
(emp_no int primary key,
 emp_name char(20),
 hire_date date,
 salary int,
 emp_manager_id varchar(20),
 dept_id integer,
   
 constraint fk_emp_manager_id foreign key (dept_id) references dept(dept_id) );
```

Comment: After correcting this, I am getting another error "invalid identifier". What does this mean?

Comment: The dept_id column was missing, I have modified the answer.